# Non-trivial convergent sequences and continuous funtctions on toplogical spaces

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topoligical spaces.

We say that $S\subset\ X$ is a non-trivial convergent sequence of $X$ if the following three conditions are fulfilled:

i) $\mathbf{card}(S)$=$\mathbf{card}\mathbb{(N)}$

ii) $\exists$ $x_0\in{S}$ such that $S\setminus${$x_0$} is a discrete space (i.e. every subset of $S\setminus${$x_o$} is open).

iii) If $V$ is a neighborhood of $x_0$ in $X$ (i.e. $V$ is an open set of $X$ such that $x_0\in{V}$ ), then $\mathbf{card}(S\setminus{V})$ $\lt$ $\mathbf{card}\mathbb{(N)}$

The exercise is to prove that if $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a continuous function, then the following statements are equivalent:

a) If $S$ is any non-trivial convergent sequence of $X$, then $f(S)$ is a non-trivial convergent sequence of $Y$.

b) For any $y\in{Y}$, $f^{-1}$({$y$}) does not contain any non-trivial convergent sequence of $X$.

I'm only missing a little part of the proof since I was able to prove the implication "a) $\Rightarrow$ b)" and, for the implication "b) $\Rightarrow$ a)", I already proved that given any non-trivial convergent sequence $S$ of $X$ it is true that $f(S)$ fulfills conditions i) and iii).

Now, since $S$ is a non-trivial convergent sequence of $X$, we know that $\exists$ $x_0\in{S}$ such that $S\setminus${$x_0$} is a discrete space. It is then natural to think that $f(x_0)\in{f(S)}$ is such that $f(S)\setminus${$f(x_0)$} is a discrete space. However, this is the part that I'm missing.

I tried to use only the cotinuity of $f$ to prove that every singleton of $f(S)\setminus${$f(x_0)$} is open (or closed) without much succes, so I guess the extra hypothesis in b) should be helpful in some way for this.

Any suggestions or hints would be aprreciated.